# mysql .net connector not working with a .net 4.0 project and connector 6.4.3 with sprocs

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures

I had to rebuild a machine here and thought I'd just redo my web site in the process.  I decided to go with mvc 3 but still use mysql on the back end.

I essentially copied and pasted all of my old code for the sql connection to return results from a mysql stored procedure and it's not working at all.  I then tried creating a simple insert sproc and it doesn't work either.  If I use in-line sql on my MySqlCommand, it works fine however (both selecting and inserting).  I'm thinking that with .net 4.0 they changed something on the CommandType.StoredProcedure...but I can't say for sure.

When I put a breakpoint on my command call to the actual sproc, it doesn't show anything, nor does it actually do anything.  I've called the sprocs from the CLI and they're working just as they should.  Back to what I was saying, I'm guessing that with .net 4, it doesn't use the "Call" command any more.  Anyone run into this issue?  If so, do you have a solution?  Is there anyway to import the System.Data 2.0 dll into a .net 4.0 project to verify what I'm thinking?

here's some code on my database layer:

```
public static BuyCollectionModel GrabBuyData(GridSettings gridSettings)
        {
            int totalRows = 0;
            BuyCollectionModel buys = new BuyCollectionModel();
            using (MySqlConnection myConnection = new MySqlConnection(AppConfig.Connection))            {

                //string sql = "SELECT 100 as totalrows, c.* FROM cBuys as c";
                //MySqlCommand myCommand = new MySqlCommand(sql, myConnection);

                MySqlCommand myCommand = new MySqlCommand("usp_GetBuys", myConnection);
                myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startrowvar", gridSettings.PageIndex);
                myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@endrowvar", gridSettings.PageSize);
                myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sortcolvar", gridSettings.SortColumn);
                myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sortordervar", gridSettings.SortOrder);
                myConnection.Open();
                using (MySqlDataReader myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (myReader.Read())
                    {
                        buys.Add(FillBuys(myReader, out totalRows));
                    }
                }
                myConnection.Close();
            }
            buys.TotalCount = totalRows;
            return buys;
        }
```

as mentioned above, I've also tried creating a simple insert sproc that works fine from the CLI, but when I call it from code using ExecuteNonQuery(), it does nothing...

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: I have a suggestion, why aren't you using some sort of ORM?  It seems silly in this day and age to be dealing with command objects directly when there are so many excellent ORM solutions out there.  I would suggest NHibernate.

Comment: or go with EntityFramework if it needs to be MS only frameworks.

Comment: Are you sure that the paramters are being passed in exactly as you would expect?  Dio you get any kind of error message at all?

Comment: replace  `using (MySqlDataReader myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (myReader.Read())
                    {
                        buys.Add(FillBuys(myReader, out totalRows));
                    }
                }`

  with                    `DataTable tmp = new DataTable();
                    tmp.Load(myCommand.ExecuteReader());` , breakpoint after the `tmp.Load(...)` call, and see if you get your results back.  if you do, i'd look at your FillBuys method

Comment: @Syska: The MySQL .NET Connector [does not easily map to EF stored procedures with parameters](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=44985). When you create a map, it leaves out all the parameters, then you have to edit the .edmx file in an XML editor to manually add the parameters... and hope you get it right. It's a real hassle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try reverting to an older version of the connector. One that works for me is 6.3.4. Also, make sure you are using the exact same version on the server as on your dev workstation.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there anyway to import the System.Data 2.0 dll into a .net 4.0 project.....

If you are running visual studio, then click on Project-> Add Reference -> Browse and find there your dlls you want to add to project.